# Alasql Query not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays, alasql

I have this alasql query I need to count a total, then if the row has a bool that is true, to count those ones. However, for whatever reason it just counts all the rows including the ones that are false.

```
var groupedShipDatesAndCabinetCounts = alasql("SELECT ShipDate, SUM(CabinetCount) AS TotalCabinetCount, SUM(CASE WHEN ShipDateConfirmed IS 1 THEN CabinetCount ELSE 0 END) AS LessCabinetCount FROM ? GROUP BY ShipDate", [shipData.TotalShipDatesAndCabinetCounts]);
```

What do I need to do to get this query working properly? I double check the data and it is all getting to this point as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't use `alasql`, but does `ShipDateConfirmed IS 1` work for you?  Should it not be `=` instead?

Comment: I ended up finding the answer. I went back to where my data was coming in and changed it there. The = sign didn't work and I had to use IS for anything to work.